# Asterisk Server - Can't make consecutive outbound calls

Tags: asterisk

One of the issues I'm having now is that if I call in consecutive times to the asterisk server **from the same phone**, it may disconnect.   Asterisk logs the following message:

```
[Aug 14 10:24:56] NOTICE[20537]: chan_sip.c:19477 handle_request_invite: Failed to authenticate device <sip:4165559999@222.222.222.222:5070>;tag=781ab8fb-co19342-INS016
```

It's like any phone in the world can only call in once to the asterisk server.  Then I need to do a

```
> sip reload
```

from the Asterisk terminal to let them call in again.

I can also do a shell command like so to reload the sip

> asterisk -rx 'sip reload'

But when I add this command to the crontab to be run every minute, it doesn't work.  The shell command only works if I run it manually.

**Can anyone tell me how I can enable callers to call my asterisk server more than once?  Here are my sip.conf and extensions.conf (all other files untouched).**

sip.conf

```
[general]
register => mysipuser:mysippass@localhost:5071
context=default

[mysipuser]
type=friend
secret=mysippass
username=mysipuser
host=111.111.111.111
port=5071
fromuser=mysipuser
canreinvite=no
insecure=very
qualify=2000
dtmfmode=inband
nat=no
context=default
```

extensions.conf

```
[default]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-extension)
exten => s,n,WaitExten()

exten => 0011,1,Goto(outbound,s,1)

exten => 11,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/5555555555) ;calls 555-555-5555
exten => 11,n,Hangup ; this line never gets executed

exten => 77,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/1111111111) ;calls 111-111-1111
exten => 77,n,Hangup ; this line never gets executed


[outbound]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-extension)
exten => s,n,WaitExten()

exten => _NXXNXXNXXX,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/${EXTEN})
exten => _NXXNXXNXXX,n,Hangup
```

**Additional Details**
I noticed that each time I execute the Dial() command in the extensions.conf, none of the lines after it gets fired, even if both parties hang up the phone.  So for example:

```
exten => 11,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/5555555555)
exten => 11,n,System(echo 'hello world'>test.txt) ; this line and any line below do not fire
exten => 11,n,Hangup
```

The code stops executing after the Dial() command...that might explain why I can't call consecutive times..it's because the line is still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new extensions.conf which seems to have solved the problem

```
[default]
exten => s,1,System(asterisk -rx 'sip reload') ; hack to force sip reload
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-extension)
exten => s,n,WaitExten()

exten => 0011,1,Goto(outbound,s,1)

exten => 11,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/5555555555,30,g) ;calls 555-555-5555
exten => 11,n,Goto(closechannel,s,1)

exten => 77,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/1111111111,30,g) ;calls 111-111-1111
exten => 77,n,Goto(closechannel,s,1)


[outbound]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-extension)
exten => s,n,WaitExten()

exten => _NXXNXXNXXX,1,Dial(SIP/mysipuser/${EXTEN})
exten => _NXXNXXNXXX,n,Hangup

[closechannel]
exten => s,1,System(asterisk -rx 'sip reload')
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

So the three changes I made were the addition of the `exten => s,1,System(asterisk -rx 'sip reload')` statement, `[closechannel]` context, and the `,30,g` to the Dial() command.  The System command forces a sip reload every time someone tries to call in. The `,g` flag tells asterisk to continue executing code after calling parties disconnect.

This seems to work "most" of the times.